# When deriving the analytic representation of Fock states , why doesn't the $\hat{P}$ operator act on the ground state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator

Starting with
\begin{align*}
    |n
\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}(\hat{a}^{\dagger})^{n}|0\rangle
\end{align*}
and
\begin{equation}
    \psi_{0}(x)=\left(\frac{m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\right) ^{\frac{1}{4}}\mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{m\omega x^{2}}{2\hbar}\right)
\end{equation}
for ladder functions defined as
\begin{equation}
    \hat{a}=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}\hat{X}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m\hbar\omega}}\hat{P}\text{,  }    \hat{a}^{\dagger}=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}\hat{X}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m\hbar\omega}}\hat{P}
\end{equation}
I derive that the analytic wavefunction for the general number state $n$ is given by:
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \psi_{n}(x)&=\langle x|n\rangle\cr
        &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}\langle x|\left(\hat{a}^{\dagger}\right)^{n}|0\rangle\cr
        &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}\langle x|\left(\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}\hat{X}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m\hbar\omega}}\hat{P}\right)^{n}|0\rangle\cr
        &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}x-\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n}\psi_{0}(x)\cr
        &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}\left(\frac{m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\right) ^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}x-\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n}\mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{m\omega x^{2}}{2\hbar}\right)
    \end{split}
\end{align}
I will call the final line of my working above expression (1).
At this point, textbooks (for example lectures on quantum mechanics gordon baym) use the identity $$H_{n}(y)=\left( 2y -\frac{d}{dy} \right)^n\cdot 1$$ (which can be proven by induction, and is only true when we have the multiplication $\cdot1$) to remove the terms in the brackets and obtain
$$
\psi_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n}n!}}\left(\frac{m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\right) ^{\frac{1}{4}}H_{n}(\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}})\mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{m\omega x^{2}}{2\hbar}\right)
$$ however this implies that the differentiation isn't acting on $\psi_{0}(x)$, which doesn't make sense, since the point is we're using the ladder operator to raise the state. any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with *the differentiation isn't acting on* $\psi_0(x)$? Can you elaborate? Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Analytical_questions) help?

Comment: So you see the expression which has $\left(\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}x-\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n}\mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{m\omega x^{2}}{2\hbar}\right)$. The $\frac{d}{dx}$ in the brackets should act on the exponential outside the brackets. However the substitution assumes that the the operator acts on $1$ outside the brackets.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand. *What* expression 'has' the formula you mention above? You should be as clear as possible and edit the question accordingly.... Perhaps it is just me not understanding the question, tho.

Comment: sorry, I meant expression (1), is that clearer now?

Comment: Your formulas are fine, but you are lost in superfluous symbols so you are misreading them! Try n=1.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos thanks for your response, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but this is what I think you mean: $(2y-\frac{d}{dy})^{1}=2y-\frac{d}{dy}(1)=2y-0=2y$ I don't see how this is at all equivalent to $(2y-\frac{d}{dy})^{1}e^{-y^{2}}=4ye^{y^{2}}$

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwhelmed by superfluous symbols which prevent you from seeing the obvious. First, non-dimensionalize junk constants by setting them
equal to one, $\sqrt{m\omega/\hbar}=1$ as practicing physicists normally do.

Then, understand the *n* =1 case,
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \psi_{1}(x)&=\langle x|1\rangle\cr
        &= \left(\frac{ 1}{4\pi }\right) ^{\frac{1}{4}}\left( x- \frac{d}{dx}\right) \mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{  x^{2}}{2 }\right) .
    \end{split}  \tag{1}
\end{align}
and  $$H_{1}(y)= 2y, ~~~~~~ H_0(y)=1.   $$
It is then evident that
$$
\psi_{1}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{ 1}{\pi }\right) ^{\frac{1}{4}} \left (2x -x -\frac{d}{dx}\right )  \exp\left(-\frac{  x^{2}}{2 }\right)= {H_1(x)\over \sqrt 2 }  \exp\left(-\frac{  x^{2}}{2 }\right),
$$
where the last two terms in the parenthesis cancel each other.

Now proceed to handle the expression for generic *n*. (Hint: associatively, $e^{x^2}\left (-\frac{d}{dx}\right )= \left (2x-\frac{d}{dx}\right ) e^{x^2}$.)

Comment: thanks, i wrapped my head around it eventually :)